# Show dropdown on Indexchanged of another dropdown .net 2.0

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, .net

I have a dropdown like this. I want another dropdown to be shown depends upon selected index changed of this dropdown.How can I do this using onchange function of javascript ?
As I am working on a old project so its on .net 2.0 that's why I cant use asp:Dropdown

```
 <select name="myselect" id="myselect" onchange="this.form.submit()">
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2">Two</option>
        <option value="3">Three</option>
        <option value="4">Four</option>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently did for cascading multi select dropwon ,please find the code below hope  it will help you.

```
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align: right;">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblCountry" runat="server" Font-Size="12px" Text="Country:" Style="margin-top: 19px !important"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td style="text-align: left;">
                    <select id="ddlCountry" multiple="multiple">
                    </select>
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="ddlCountryHid" runat="server" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align: right">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblState" runat="server" Font-Size="12px" Text="State:" Style="margin-top: 19px !important"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td style="text-align: left;">
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="ddlStateHid" runat="server" />
                    <select id="ddlState" multiple="multiple" style="margin-left: 5px;">
                    </select>

                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

**Javascript**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Index.aspx/GetCountry",
            data: '',
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                for (var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {
                    $("#ddlCountry").append($("<option></option>").val(data.d[i].Id).html(data.d[i].Name));
                }

                //for multiselect
                $('#ddlCountry').multiselect({
                    includeSelectAllOption: true
                });
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Index.aspx/GetSelctedCountry",
                    data: '',
                    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        var valArr = data.d.split(',');
                        i = 0, size = valArr.length;
                        //  //for multiselect  show the selcted country as selected if
                        for (var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {
                            $("#ddlCountry").find(":checkbox[value='" + valArr[i] + "']").attr("checked", "checked");
                            $("#ddlCountry option[value='" + valArr[i] + "']").attr("selected", 1).change();
                            $("#ddlCountry").multiselect("refresh");
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (err) {

                    }
                });
            },
            error: function (err) {

            }
        });
        var obj = {};
        obj.state = '';
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Index.aspx/GetState",
            data: JSON.stringify(obj),
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                for (var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {
                    $("#ddlState").append($("<option></option>").val(data.d[i].Id).html(data.d[i].Name));
                }
                var obj = $("#MainContent_ChildContent2_ddlCountryHid").val();
                //for multiselect
                $('#ddlState').multiselect({
                    includeSelectAllOption: true,
                    height: 50,
                });

                $('#ddlState').multiselect("disable");
            },
            error: function (err) {

            }
        });
        $('#ddlState').change(function () {
            var d1 = '';
            $('#ddlState :checked').each(function (i) {
                d1 = d1 + $(this).val() + ',';
            });
            $("#MainContent_ChildContent2_ddlStateHid").val(d1);
        });
        $('#ddlCountry').change(function () {
            var d = '';
            $('#ddlCountry :checked').each(function (i) {
                d = d + $(this).val() + ',';
            });
            $("#MainContent_ChildContent2_ddlCountryHid").val(d);
            var obj = {};
            obj.state = d;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Index.aspx/GetState",
                data: JSON.stringify(obj),
                contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    var data1 = '';
                    $('#ddlState option').each(function (index, option) {
                        if (data1 == '')
                            data1 = $(option);
                        $(option).remove();
                    });
                    //for multiselect
                    $('#ddlState').multiselect({
                        includeSelectAllOption: true
                    });
                    if (data.d.length == 0) {
                        $("#ddlState").append($("<option></option>").val('').html('')).multiselect("destroy").multiselect();
                        $("#ddlState").attr('disable', 'disable');
                    }


                    for (var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {
                        $("#ddlState").append($("<option></option>").val(data.d[i].Id).html(data.d[i].Name));
                    }
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "Index.aspx/GetSelectedState",
                        data: '',
                        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (data) {
                            var valArr = data.d.split(',');
                            i = 0, size = valArr.length;
                            //for multiselect show by default selected
                            for (i; i < size; i++) {
                                $("#ddlState").find(":checkbox[value='" + valArr[i] + "']").attr("checked", "checked");
                                $("#ddlState option[value='" + valArr[i] + "']").attr("selected", 1);
                                $("#ddlState").multiselect("refresh");
                            }
                        },
                        error: function (err) {

                        }
                    });

                    $('#ddlState').multiselect('rebuild');
                    $('#ddlState').multiselect({
                        includeSelectAllOption: true
                    });
                    if (data.d.length == 0)
                        $('#ddlState').multiselect("disable");
                    else
                        $('#ddlState').multiselect("enable");

                },
                error: function (err) {
                }
            });
        });
        $('#testid').click(function () {
            $('#ddlState option').prop('selected', true);
        });
    });


</script>
```